# Разный текст в заивисмости от страницы сайта

Tags: битрикс, header

Всем привет! Нужно на отдельную страницу (которая будет определятся по url) вывести другой текст с одной страницы которая используется везде как шапка сайта. Вот сам текст:

Международная Академия Туризма в Анталии

на страницы школы например нужно вывести Международная Школа в Анталии.
Как это можно реализовать? Заранее спасибо! Сайт на битриксе

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();?> <a href="/" title="Eduant" > 
<style>
.reg-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 86px;
  right: 17px;
  background: #ff9b59 !important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff9b59, #e05a00) !important;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff9b59, #e05a00) !important;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff9b59, #e05a00) !important;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff9b59, #e05a00) !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ff9b59, #e05a00) !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7;
  -moz-border-radius: 7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #666666 !important;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 16px !important;
  padding: 5px 12px 5px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
  border: solid #dedede 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.reg-btn:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd !important;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #0e7dc7) !important;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #0e7dc7) !important;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #0e7dc7) !important;
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3cb0fd, #0e7dc7) !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #0e7dc7) !important;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
</style>
 
  <div id="company_logo"></div>
 </a> 
<div class="subtitle">Международная Академия Туризма в Анталии</div>
 
<p align="left" style="color: rgb(18, 61, 116); font-size: 100%;"> Турция: <strong>+90 (242) 324 2407</strong> Россия: <strong>+7 (499) 703 02 36</strong> Казахстан: <strong>+7 (727) 350 53 56</strong><a href="http://zingaya.com/widget/e301d0330f634c3892312b08949d834d" onclick="window.open(this.href+'?referrer='+escape(window.location.href)+'', '_blank', 'width=236,height=220,resizable=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,status=no'); return false" class="zingaya_button1366099122678" ></a></p>
 <a href="http://eduant.ru/forms/form3.php" class="reg-btn" >Регистрация абитуриентов</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

**Определяем текущую страницу** ([подробнее](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/getcurpage.php))

Просто проверяем текущую страницу и для неё выводим свою строку.

Пример кода в header:

```
<?if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false) !== '/page/'): ?> 
    <div class="subtitle">Международная Академия Туризма в Анталии</div>
<? endif;?>
```

**Выводим значение из свойства** ([подробнее](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/getproperty.php))

Создаём свойство для страницы. Потом добавляем значение для главного раздела и на страницах или разделах переопределяем значение свойства.

Пример кода в header:

```
<? $subtitle = $APPLICATION->GetProperty("subtitle");
     if (strlen($subtitle)>0) echo $subtitle;
  else
     echo "Международная Академия Туризма в Анталии";?>
```

**Выводим значение из включаемой области** ([подробнее](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=34&LESSON_ID=1879))

Для этого создаём общую включаемую область и подключаем её, а в нужных разделах переопределяем её.

Comment: Спасибо большое, код который я дал выше можно так изменить, чтобы название выводилось в зависимости от страницы нахождения пользователя, сам код который выше, он исполняется на всех страницах в шапке сайте. Попробовал методами которые вы написали выше, не получилось.
Мне всего-то нужно, чтобы на этой странице eduant.ru/school/ выводилось название - Международная Русская Школа.

Comment: Попробовал вывести так - <?if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false) !== '/school/'): ?> 
<div class="subtitle">Международная Академия Туризма в Анталии</div>
 <? endif;?> 
Но теперь на странице school соответственно пусто, надписи нет, вопрос как ее вставить? else внутри этого кода не работает (я нуб в php и html)

Comment: Вы тогда сделайте `<?if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false) == '/school/'): ?>`

Comment: <div class="subtitle">Международная Академия Туризма в Анталии</div>
 </a> <?if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false) == '/school/'): ?> 
<div class="subtitle">Международная Русская Школа в Анталии</div>
 <? endif;?>

Comment: Сделал так, но теперь 2 проблемы, выводятся сразу 2 надписи в /school/ и если перейти допустим /school/training/, выводится уже другая надпись, нужна Международная Русская Школа а выходит Международная Академия.
...

Comment: `<?if ($APPLICATION->GetCurPage(false) == '/school/'): ?> <div class="subtitle">Международная Русская Школа в Анталии</div> <?else:?><div class="subtitle">Международная Академия Туризма в Анталии</div><? endif;?>`

Comment: Тогда Вам не подходит этот вариант используйте 2 вариант